# tailwind classes are not being applied when using hamburger functionality

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, navbar, hamburger-menu

I'm trying to implement a hamburger functionality by myself and it worked out fine. But when i'm testing it on mobile device nav links are being treated as normal text. tailwind classes aren't being applied and when hovering not even links are showing down the screen. here's the code

```
//imports
const Nav = () => {
  //usestates

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setIsVisible(!isVisible);
  };
  //darkmode function
  const handleThemeSwitch = () => {
    setTheme(theme === "dark" ? "light" : "dark");
  };

  return (
    <header className="padding-x py-8 absolute z-10 w-full">
      <nav className="flex justify-between items-center max-container relative">
        <a href="/">
          <img src={headerLogo} alt="Logo" width={130} height={29}></img>
        </a>
        <ul
          className={`flex-1 flex max-lg:flex-col justify-center items-center  ${
            isVisible
              ? "bg-coral-red absolute top-28 left-16 w-[70%] rounded-2xl transition-all duration-1000 gap-10 flex"
              : "max-lg:hidden"
          }`}
        >
          {navLinks.map((item) => (
            <li
              key={item.label}
              className="hover:scale-105 rounded-full hover:bg-red-50 p-4 transition-all dduration-700 ease-in-out cursor-pointer pt-5"
            >
              <a
                href={item.href}
                className="font-montserrat leading-normal text-slate-gray text-xl"
              >
                {item.label}
              </a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <div>
          <div className="flex gap-2">
            <div
              className="p-4 lg:p-5 rounded-2xl dark:bg-gray-500 bg-gray-300 dark:lg:bg-slate-200 cursor-pointer"
              onClick={handleThemeSwitch}
            >
              {theme === "dark" ? <BsFillSunFill /> : <BsMoonStarsFill />}
            </div>

            {isVisible ? (
              <ImCross
                alt="hamburger"
                className="hidden max-lg:block h-9 w-9 pt-2"
                onClick={handleButtonClick}
              />
            ) : (
              <GiHamburgerMenu
                className="hidden max-lg:block h-9 w-9 pt-2"
                onClick={handleButtonClick}
              />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. The code is fine the problem was with hero section. hero section title had z-10 that's why when I was hovering I wasn't actually hovering over the nav-links